# Replace default message for Constraint Validator

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to change the default message of a Constraint Validator in Spring.

I tried adding the new message depending on the validation error like this:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("My custom message").addConstraintViolation();
```

for every case.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(MyData data, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getDocumentType())) {
        if (data.getDocumentType().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            valid = isValidTypeN(data.getDocument());
            if(!valid) context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("My custom message for type N").addConstraintViolation();
        } else if(data.getDocumentType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){
            valid = isValidTypeR(data.getDocument());
            if(!valid) context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("My custom message for type R").addConstraintViolation();
        } else if(data.getDocumentType.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
            valid = isValidTypeP(data.getDocument());
            if(!valid) context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("My custom message for type P").addConstraintViolation();
        }
    }       
    return valid;
}
```

But this is adding a new message not replacing the default message from the Constraint so when I show the errors in the form page, it shows both of them the default and the one I added instead of only the one I added dynamically.

Comment: what have you set as default in the annotation?

Comment: just a default message `String message() default "whatever this is a default message"`

Comment: so, you can either change that, or change it by passing a value to the annotation

Comment: Obviously. But my question is about changing that value dinamically depending on the error type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should do the job:

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation()
```